# How to rearrange $x + 2y + z = 50$ for $y$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, solution-verification

I am trying to rearrange $x + 2y + z = 50$ for $y$, but I am unsure if I am doing it correctly.

Here is what I am doing:

$$2y + z = 50 - x$$
$$2y = 50 - x - z$$
$$\therefore y = 50 - x - \frac {z} {2}$$

Is that correct? Thanks.

Comment: Firstly the tag of polynomials is not correct. If you are re-arranging in terms of $y$ then nearly, careful you need to divide everything on the RHS by 2 so that $$y=\frac{(50-x-z)}{2}$$

Comment: ... though ironically, you _don't_ need to write brackets if you use a fraction bar like @fundamentalform does.

Comment: your last equation should be `y = (50-x-z)/2`

Comment: @980stack For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on MathJax notation](/help/notation), [MathJax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: The OP originally wrote the final formula as $y=50-x-z/2$. The "PEDMAS" convention interprets this as $y=(50-x)-(z/2)$, whereas the correct answer (fully parenthesized) is $y=((50-x)-z)/2$. The important thing is that when you move the $2$ in $2y=50-x-z$ from left to right, it divides *all* of $50-x-z$, not just the $z$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your question, yes, your solution is correct, but only to a certain extent. It is important to note that in the last step of your solution, **all** terms on the RHS must be divided by 2.

The original equation was as follows:

$$x + 2y + z = 50$$

To rearrange for $y$, simple move the terms without $y$ to the RHS i.e. subtract the terms without $y$ from both sides of the equation.

$$x + 2y + z - x - z = 50 - x - z$$

$$2y = 50 - x - z$$

Finally, to rearrange for $y$ alone, divide **all** terms on the RHS by $2$.

$$y = \frac {50 - x - z} {2}$$

If you are unsure whether your answer is correct for such questions, simply substitute the value of $y$ that you have found into the original equation.

Substituting $y = \frac {50 - x - z} {2} \ $ into our original equation,

$$x + 2 \cdot \frac {50 - x - z} {2} + z = 50$$
$$x + (50 - x - z) + z = 50$$
$$50 = 50$$

Since the LHS = RHS, the answer is correct.

I hope that helps!

Comment: I think it's worthwhile noting that the OP's answer is not correct as written as (s)he has only divided the $z$ term by $2$.

Comment: @fundamentalform I understood it as the whole being divided by $2$, as the OP does not seem to know how to use MathJax. Nevertheless, I hope that this answer clarifies any doubts the OP might have.

Comment: Yes, you understood it correctly, as I did. But we do not know if the OP understood it as such, given what was written and that's why it's worthwhile noting the error.

Comment: @fundamentalform True, I will edit the answer accordingly. Thank you.

Comment: @fundamentalform what i meant was (50-x-z)/2 but mistakenly written  50-x-z/2.

Comment: @AnitejPalur thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @980stack Yes, I assumed you meant as such. At least you are now aware that it is important to specify exactly what the numerator and denominator of a fraction are in such cases. I would suggest checking out some of the links mentioned in soupless' comment for help on writing mathematics on this site. Nevertheless, I am happy you found my answer helpful. :)